# my python code keeps crashing but I dont see any problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

im making a chatbot but after a lot of changes I tried testing it but the only thing that happened is that it crashed and I see no problems in the code ? can anyone help ?

edit : now theres an error on line 8 (the start on jokes array)

heres my code :

```
import time
import random

chatbotline = 'Chatbot : '
questions = ['How do you do ?','Whats your name ?','How old are you ?','What do you like to do ?','Whats your favorite movie ?'
,'Whats your favorite book ?','Do you like chatting with me ?','Whats your favorite snack ?','Whats your favorite video game ?']

jokes = ['I ate a clock yesterday, it was very time-consuming.','A perfectionist walked into a bar...apparently, the bar wasn’t set high enough.',
'Did you hear about the crook who stole a calendar? He got twelve months.','Ive just written a song about tortillas. actually, it’s more of a rap.'
]

def main():
    print('What whould you like to do ?')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    options = input('1.Questions\n2.Jokes\n3.Opinion\n4.Exit\n')
    if(options == 1) :
    questionpick()
def questionget():
    questiongot = random.choice(questions)
    main()
def questionask():

def questionpick():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('Do you want to ask questions ?')
    questoptions = input('1.Yes\n2.No, you \n')
    if(questoptions = 1) :
        questionask()
    elif(questoptions = 2) :
        questionget()




print('starting up...')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Chatbot : Hello im chatbot your new friend !')
time.sleep(0.2)
print('Chatbot : So what do you want to do today ?')
time.sleep(0.2)
options = input('1.Questions\n2.Jokes\n3.Opinion\n4.Exit\n')
if(options == 1) :
    questionpick()
```

Comment: `questionask()` is empty and throws a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something in `questionask`:

```
def questionask():
    pass
    # or more useful code, actually
```

Answer (score 0):

The version below was tested without error.
There was indentation error (line 17) + the comparison in python is made with `==` and note just `=`

```
import time
import random

chatbotline = 'Chatbot : '
questions = ['How do you do ?','Whats your name ?','How old are you ?','What do you like to do ?','Whats your favorite movie ?'
,'Whats your favorite book ?','Do you like chatting with me ?','Whats your favorite snack ?','Whats your favorite video game ?']

jokes = ['I ate a clock yesterday, it was very time-consuming.','A perfectionist walked into a bar...apparently, the bar wasn’t set high enough.',
'Did you hear about the crook who stole a calendar? He got twelve months.','Ive just written a song about tortillas. actually, it’s more of a rap.'
]

def main():
    print('What whould you like to do ?')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    options = input('1.Questions\n2.Jokes\n3.Opinion\n4.Exit\n')
    if(options == 1):
        questionpick()

def questionget():
    questiongot = random.choice(questions)
    main()

def questionask():
    pass

def questionpick():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('Do you want to ask questions ?')
    questoptions = input('1.Yes\n2.No, you \n')
    if(questoptions == 1):
        questionask()
    elif(questoptions == 2):
        questionget()


print('starting up...')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Chatbot : Hello im chatbot your new friend !')
time.sleep(0.2)
print('Chatbot : So what do you want to do today ?')
time.sleep(0.2)
options = input('1.Questions\n2.Jokes\n3.Opinion\n4.Exit\n')
if(options == 1) :
    questionpick()
```